# Bijection between subsets of a Set is an Equivalence Relation in its Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working through Halmos's book and find in Section 12 the claim that an equivalence or bijection between subsets of some set $X$ is an equivalence relation in the power set $P(X)$.

Intuitively, this is reasonable, and Halmos claims that it's easy to verify.

My approach is to note that a bijection, or what Halmos calls an equivalence $\sim$, between subsets $A,B,C$ behaves very much like reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

I'm having a problem verifying the corresponding equivalence relation in $P(X)$. My hunch is to build a map from $X$ to its power set and show that it preserves the structure of the bijection in $X$ as a relation in $P(X)$. If this is a good approach, do I need to explicitly state the mapping or function?

Perhaps building a function is overkill, but it seems that simply observing that $A \sim B$ and $B \sim A$, and the like, in $X$ is similar to $ARB, BRA$ in $P(X)$ does not quite verify this claim.

Comment: If I understand this correctly the *relation* is as follows: for $A,B \in P(X), A \sim B$ if and only if there is a bijection $f: A\longrightarrow B$. This you need to prove an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand how a map form $X$ to $P(X)$ could help to solve your problem (notice that this map can never be bijective).

If you want to do what @Krish said in the comments, the result follows from the fact that the identity map is bijective (what gives reflexivity), composition of bijections is a bijection (what gives transitivity) and the inverse of a bijection is bijective (what gives symmetry). Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) to clarify what is an equivalence relation.